# Using std::variant

Tags: c++, variant-type

Have been using `std::variant` for the first time.

Accidentally stumbled on a pattern that seems resonable but wanted to get a second opinion.

I have a class that can contain value (its for another language simulation). To represent this in C++ I though the value can use a variant and thus I can retain type safety. But now I need to get the data out and using `std::variant::index` works but is less readable in the code than I want. So I initially added a type object to the class that I kept in sync with the variant:

Think:

```
// Note: This is not the code for review.
//       This is to give context.

class Object {/*Stuff*/}
enum class DataType = {Integer, Double, String, Bool, Object};
using DataValue = std::vaiant<int, double, std::string, bool, Object>;

class Value
{
    DataType   typeInfo;
    DataValue  value;

    public:
        // Removed constructors for clarity.

        DataType type() const {return typeInfo;}
        template<typename T>
        T const& get()  const {return std::get<T>(value);}
};
```

This way I to perform actions on the value I can use a switch:

```
void doAction(Value& v)
{
    switch (v.type()) {
        case DataType::Integer: doAction(v.get<int>());break;
        case DataType::Double:  doAction(v.get<double>());break;
        case DataType::String:  doAction(v.get<std::string>());break;
        case DataType::Bool:    doAction(v.get<bool>());break;
        case DataType::Object:  doAction(v.get<Object>());break;
    }
}
```

So two things stand out to me.

1. In the `get<X>()` the `X` does not match the `DataType::X` apart form `Object`.
2. I have stored an extra type object (I am sure that variant is already got).

---

To the code to review:

I changed two things. I don't store the extra typeInfo object (I calculate it from value) and I add some extra type aliases to make the code cleaner and easier to read:

This is what my code looks like now:

```
namespace ThorsAnvil::Anvil::Ice
{

class Object {/*Stuff*/}
enum class DataType = {Integer, Double, String, Bool, Object};
using Integer = int;
using Double  = double;
using String  = std::string;
using Bool    = std::bool;
using DataValue = std::vaiant<Integer, Double, String, Bool, Object>;

class Value
{
    DataValue  value;

    public:
        // Removed constructors for clarity.

        DataType type() const {return static_cast<DataType>(value.index());}
        template<typename T>
        T const& get()  const {return std::get<T>(value);}

        Value toInteger(Value& v) const
        {
            switch (v.type()) {
                case DataType::Integer: return Value{get<Integer>()};break;
                case DataType::Double:  return Value{static_cast<int>(get<Double>())};break;
                case DataType::String:  return Value{std::atoi(get<String>().c_str())};break;
                case DataType::Bool:    return Value{get<Bool>()? 1 : 0};break;
                case DataType::Object:  return Value{get<Object>().toNumber()};break;
            }
        }

};

}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use `std::visit()`

What you want can be done using [`std::visit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). For example, you can write:

```
using DataValue = std::variant<int, double, std::string, bool, Object>;

void doAction(DataValue& v) {
    std::visit([](auto& v){ doAction(v); }, v);
}
```

This basically is equivalent to your `doAction()`, but now it works directly on a `std::variant` instead of on your wrapper class. You of course still need to provide the specializations of `doAction()` for each of the types of the variant.

If you want to write a single, compact `toInteger()` function, then you can use the [`struct overloaded` trick](https://tamir.dev/posts/that-overloaded-trick-overloading-lambdas-in-cpp17/):

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

DataValue toInteger(const DataValue& v) {
    return std::visit(overloaded{
        [](const int& v)         { return v; },
        [](const double& v)      { return static_cast<int>(v); },
        [](const std::string& v) { return std::stoi(v); },
        [](const bool& v)        { return v ? 1 : 0; },
        [](const Object& v)      { return v.toNumber(); }
    }, v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's nice. Have not used `std::visit()` (or heard about it).